# How to combine and print values of nested object structure?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes and each hash needs to be printed out on the same line.

```rb
init_cards_j = [
  { init1: [{ num: 6, head: 1 }, { num: 10, head: 1 }] },
  { init2: [{ num: 53, head: 1 }, { num: 60, head: 1 }] },
  { init3: [{ num: 77, head: 5 }] },
  { init4: [{ num: 89, head: 1 }] }
]
```

I want it to be looked like this:

```rb
Card 6: 1 head / Card 10: 1 head
Card 53: 1 head / Card 60: 1 head
Card 77: 5 head
Card 89: 1 haed
```

I tried below:

```rb
init_cards_j.each_index do |index|
  init_cards_j[index].values[0].each do |pair|
    init_cards_j[index].each do |key, value|
      value.each do |pair|
        puts "Card #{pair[:num]}: #{pair[:head]} kettle head. / "
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which outputs the data as:

```
Card 6: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 10: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 6: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 10: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 53: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 60: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 53: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 60: 1 kettle head. / 
Card 77: 5 kettle head. / 
Card 89: 1 kettle head. /
```

I am sorry that my array is so nested as I need to sort the order by `num` for each hash, I put them in an array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it should be 5 head. My bad! Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the hashes in `init_cards_j` via [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) and for each hash call [`each_value`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) to traverse its values. Then, instead of printing every card right away, you can generate an intermediate array via [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) the result using your separator string:

```
init_cards_j.each do |hash|
  hash.each_value do |values|
    puts values.map { |c| "Card #{c[:num]}: #{c[:head]} head" }.join(' / ')
  end
end
```

But it would be easier to convert the array of hashes to a single hash: (assuming that their keys are unique)

```
cards = {
  init1: [{ num: 6, head: 1 }, { num: 10, head: 1 }],
  init2: [{ num: 53, head: 1 }, { num: 60, head: 1 }],
  init3: [{ num: 77, head: 5 }],
  init4: [{ num: 89, head: 1 }]
}
```

If you must retain the given structure, you could convert it on the fly:

```
cards = init_cards_j.inject(&:merge)
```

This makes the loop a bit simpler:

```
cards.each_value do |values|
  puts values.map { |c| "Card #{c[:num]}: #{c[:head]} head" }.join(' / ')
end
```

To further refine the output, you can separate the looping from the card description by extracting the latter into a method:

```
def description(card)
  "Card #{card[:num]}: #{card[:head]} head"
end

init_cards_j.each do |hash|
  hash.each_value do |values|
    puts values.map { |card| description(card) }.join(' / ')
  end
end
```

You can now adding more logic to the output string by editing the `description` method, e.g.:

```
def description(card)
  if card[:head] == 1
    "Card #{card[:num]}: #{card[:head]} head"
  else
    "Card #{card[:num]}: #{card[:head]} heads"
  end
end
```

The above can be written much more compact, but I'll leave the optimization to you.

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan, you made my day! I want to cast a up vote but I don't have enough reputation to do it yet :(

Comment: @RhonaLam no worries, you can cast a vote at a later time if you want to :-)

Comment: I have edited the question now, thanks :) Now I want to add a bit of logic in to check if :head if > 1, is yes I want to print 'heads' instead of 'head' but I cant' figure out how to do it.
```ruby
  init_cards_j.each do |hash|
    hash.each_value do |values|
        values.map do |c|
            if c[:head] > 1
                puts ["Card #{c[:num]}: #{c[:head]} heads"].join(' | ')
            else
                puts ["Card #{c[:num]}: #{c[:head]} head"].join(' | ')
            end
         end
    end
  end
```

This back to new line for each k-v pair :(

Comment: Oh, did I not doing it right? Why my codes are now in one line instead of block?

Comment: @RhonaLam in my code, `map` returns the strings for the cards of one line as an array. `join` turns that array onto a single string and `puts` prints it. By moving `puts` and `join` into the `map` block, you change that logic: you are now printing each card string right away and `map` becomes useless.

Comment: That's why is not working, I see. So I have to do the login separately and tried to corporate in it?

Comment: @RhonaLam if you want to change the output string, you have to modify the part that builds the string and _only_ that part. I've added another example, showing a way to add an `if` expression by first extracting the string building into its own method. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend @Stefan's first answer, but here is another way to achieve the same result.

We might begin with a helper method, which of course you can test separately:

```
def print_num_and_head(g)
  print "Card %d: %d head" % g.values_at(:num, :head)
end
```

If

```
g = {:num=>6, :head=>1})
```

then

```
print_num_and_head(g)
```

displays

```
Card 6: 1 head
```

without a line terminator.

We may then write:

```
init_cards_j.each do |h|
  _, (g, *arr) = h.flatten
  print_num_and_head(g)
  arr.each do |g|
    print ' / '
    print_num_and_head(g)
  end
  puts   
end
```

prints

```
Card 6: 1 head / Card 10: 1 head
Card 53: 1 head / Card 60: 1 head
Card 77: 5 head
Card 89: 1 head
```

Here I've used Ruby's powerful [array#decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) (a.k.a *array disambiguation*) syntax to advantage:

If

```
h = { init1: [{ num: 6, head: 1 }, { num: 10, head: 1 }] }
```

then

```
_, (g, *arr) = h.flatten
  #=> [:init1, [{:num=>6, :head=>1}, {:num=>10, :head=>1}]]
_ #=> :init1
g #=> {:num=>6, :head=>1}
arr
  #=> [{:num=>10, :head=>1}]
```

I've employed the common convention of representing a block variable with an underscore when it is not used in the block calculation.

See [this article](https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/) for a fuller explanation array decomposition.

Comment: Thanks Cary for your very detailed explanation, I learnt a lot :) I will definitely check out the array decomposition's article.